# Can I use losses from sale of stock to offset capital gains from sale of property

Tags: income-tax, canada, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

If I make a capital gain from the sale of a house but make capital losses from the sale of stocks in my brokerage account (not tax sheltered), then can I use the losses against the gains to reduce my tax?

Can I also carry forward losses/gains backward/forward even if gains came from sale of property and losses came from sale of stocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capital losses from the sale of stocks can be used to offset capital gains from the sale of a house, assuming that house was a rental property the whole time.  If it was your principal residence, the capital gains are not taxed.  If you used it as both a rental and a principal residence, then it gets more complicated: http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/127/rsdnc/menu-eng.html